# Killing Air Starcraft 2 Devil's Playground

Tags: starcraft-2

I must have done 5 levels already and thought it was TOO EASY. Now i am on Devil's Playground and find it annoying and now difficult due to the flying units coming and killing all my units.

It looks like the only unit i have that can kill air is the marine. This sucks up too much money and they die easy along. How do i kill air units in this level and what units should i build? atm i have been building about 4/7 reapers, 1/7 medics and 2/7 marines. The marines just die to quickly and i am not using enough gas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Depending on which order you're doing the missions in, you can probably get mercenary marines too.

2) Use more Medics. With units like mutalisks, you probably want more medics than 1/7, probably closer to 3.

3) Build defenses (Turrets and Bunkers). Most of the air attacks came to my first base, 1 bunker (marine, marine, firebat, marauder) 1 turret, 2 SCVs was more than enough to fend off all attacks.

Note) Reapers are nice, but they are most effective against buildings, or exploiting terrain (hitting a weak side up a cliff), they work okay in a group with marines.

Here's what I did (hard difficulty):

After initial defenses at my main base (the aforementioned bunker defenses), I got a few reapers, and traveled around the north area collecting pallets and more reapers. Running back to the medics at the base as needed.

Then, as I needed to move to other bases (heading south towards the brutalisk next), I used the provided secondary command center with 4 mercenary marines and a few medics with the 6-8 Reapers to protect it. The attacks against it were minor, but I did build a bunker and had an SCV repairing it.

I generally used this same force (3-4 medics, 4-6 mercenary marines in the bunker, 6-8 reapers) wherever I moved the command center. The reapers would jump ahead to the next mineral deposit to clear out the enemies, and run back to the medics as needed, and the rest would stay by the bunker which was just up the hill from the minerals.

I was able to completely eliminate the enemy's bases, and got the "Scenic route" achievement.

Comment: This is right. I didnt realize reapers were most effective against buildings (BUT i was using them right the entire time). I had to many reaps and not enough marines/medics. I slowed down (not attempting to mind a full area every wave) and then it wasnt so bad. I continued off the save where i gave up. I rebuilt all my SCVs and units (making my 4k to 2k) and did the rest without much of a problem. It took me 1h20 mins `*is embarrassed*`. Thats 2-3x longer then all the maps before it. But also it had my biggest F up

Comment: NOTE for others. I had like 10medics, 15marines and 10 or so reapers at mid game and contuniously build to keep them up. Maries died the fastest and i constantly healed my reapers. Like attack 2builds heal. Fight an enemy attack no building, heal.

Comment: 1h20 min isn't that bad if you got the Scenic Route achievement. That's about how long it took me? Maybe a little closer to an hour?

Comment: seriously? Maybe I did something different but I completed it in 40 minutes and cleared every zerg off the bored.  Were you playing on insane?

Comment: @tzenes: I actually started it in brutal but got annoyed when my units died quickly and how long it was taking to finish so i did it on hard (one level easier)

Answer (score 1):

This strategy will carry you through 90% of the early missions in SC2 (even on brutal).

-Do not stop building SCVs (seriously, DO. NOT. STOP. EVER.)

-Do not build any units for the first minute or two, just SCVs

-Construct 4-6 barracks and add tech labs to half of them.

-Mass marines and medics. (Make sure you get the stim and shield upgrades in the armory)

-Upgrade attack and defense in engineering bay.

-Win game.

Comment: Sounds mineral intensive.